# Understanding Callbacks and Closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, closures

I'm a JavaScript beginner and just finished reading "JavaScript The good parts". Now, I'm trying to understand and demystify closure and callbacks in JavaScript.
Below is a piece of code which I assume should produce numbers from 1 through 10. However the code fails to compile (I'm using node btw).

```
var someAsyncFn = function() {};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        someAsycFn(function() {
            console.log(j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
        someAsycFn(function() {
        ^
ReferenceError: someAsycFn is not defined
```

Comment: Please note that the error of the missing 'n' has been removed. However I'm unable to print the numbers from 1 through 10.

Answer (score 2):

You've made a spelling error:

```
var someAsyncFn = function() {};
someAsycFn(function() {
```

Your call to the function omits the letter `n`.

---

The reason it doesn't work at all is that this is not real code. It is an example. `someAsyncfn` is not a real function. It does nothing. `var someAsyncFn = function() {};` makes a function that does nothing. It's a placeholder to describe what would happen if there was a real asynchronous function.

Something like this would show the effect in a web browser (you'd need to use a different asynchronous function in node.js; I'm using jQuery to keep the code clean).

```
var someAsyncFn = function(successfn) {
    $.get(document.location, successfn); // make an AJAX request to the current URL, for demonstration purposes
                                         // successfn will be called when the request succeeds
};
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(j) {
        someAsyncFn(function() {
            console.log(j);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

This works because (a) the function containing `console.log` is now actually called and (b) because it is called asynchronously, when the `$.get` request is complete.

The whole point of this is that the code runs asynchronously, which means you won't get `0` to `9` in order; you'll get them in the order that the requests completed. For me, this was:

```
2
3
1
0
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

You will probably get a different result.

Comment: @lonesomeday, have you got a working example of the code (jQuery or node.js) to explain your answer better?